# Native Modules trouble with Java - Cannot use GET_USAGE_STATS

Tags: java, react-native

We need to be able to request the GET_USAGE_STATS permission if it is not already enabled on the device. I found some code I somewhat understand that uses the usage stats if its already enabled. However, if its not enabled, it just silently fails and does not send the user to the settings page, so I copied another library's implementation of requesting permission, but I am getting some errors I don't fully understand. Code snippet below:

```
import android.app.usage.UsageEvents;
import android.app.usage.UsageStats;
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager;
import android.app.AppOpsManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UsageStatsModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public UsageStatsModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "UsageStats";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void getEvents(ReadableMap readableMap, Promise promise) {
    try {
      WritableArray returnArray = Arguments.createArray();
      UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService("usagestats");
      UsageEvents uEvents = usm.queryEvents(Long.parseLong(readableMap.getString("starttime")), Long.parseLong(readableMap.getString("endtime")));
      while (uEvents.hasNextEvent()){
        UsageEvents.Event e = new UsageEvents.Event();
        uEvents.getNextEvent(e);
        WritableArray tArray = Arguments.createArray();
        tArray.pushString(e.getPackageName());
        tArray.pushString(String.valueOf(e.getEventType()));
        tArray.pushString(String.valueOf(e.getTimeStamp()));
        returnArray.pushArray(tArray);
      }
      promise.resolve(returnArray);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }

 // CODE I ADDED
  private boolean isAccessGranted() {
    try {
      PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
      ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(reactContext.getPackageName(), 0);
      AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
      int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
      return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // METHOD I CREATED BASED ON ANOTHER LIBRARY's PERMISSION REQUEST
  @ReactMethod
  public void requestPermission(final Promise promise) {
    if (!isAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        reactContext.startActivityForResult(intent, 0, bundle);
    }
    if (isAccessGranted()) {
      promise.resolve("");
    } else {
      promise.reject("");
    }
  }
}
```

Upon attempting to compile the above code, I am getting some errors stating that it cannot find certain symbols within the code, but the packages it's pointing to are clearly imported at the top of the file. Having never worked with Java, does the order of the imports matter? Do I need to do any destructuring like I do with JavaScript? Errors below for reference.

```
    error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:------\app\src\main\java\com\---\UsageStatsModule.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
      PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getPackageManager()
  location: class UsageStatsModule
C:------\app\src\main\java\com\---\UsageStatsModule.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
      ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(reactContext.getPackageName(), 0);
      ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationInfo
  location: class UsageStatsModule
C:------\app\src\main\java\com\---\UsageStatsModule.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
      AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method getSystemService(String)
  location: class UsageStatsModule
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors
```